# Selenium 3.7.1 (Java) and ChromeDriver 2.33.5

Tags: java, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I'm having an issue with launching Google Chrome using Selenium's latest version as of today 3.7.1

It works fine if it's within the IDE, but when I export to jar file and try running it, nothing happens. It used to work on Selenium 3.4.0, after upgrading it no longer works.

I'm not sure if it's a bug in Selenium's version or what exactly, Is anyone experiencing the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Long story short, does Selenium 3.7.1 work with ChromeDriver 2.33.5 when executing the jar file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB I've edited the original post.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by including all 3.7.1 libraries into the build path. 3.7.1 works different than 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

As per latest release of selenium 3.7 , you should use v2.33 of chrome driver as there is no other driver is released by chromium yet. And I guess it should work

Comment: thanks for your comment, but as stated I'm already using the latest version version of chrome driver.